# Transparent context menu item during Thunderbird addon development

Tags: xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Currently i am developing a context menu addon for Thunderbird 3*. I am trying to add my own Submenu items as part of existing Thunderbird Context menu for mail content.

With the following XUL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <overlay id="sample" 
         xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
         <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://elane/content/expoverlay.js"/>
    <popup id="mailContext"> 
    <menu id="elMenu" label="submenu 1">
        <popup id="elMenu-popup">
            <menuitem id="openBing" 
                      label="Sub Menu Item 1" 
                      oncommand="openURL('https://bing.com')"/>
            <menuitem id="openGoogle" 
                      label="Sub Menu Item 2" 
                      oncommand="openURL('https://google.com')"/>
        </popup>
    </menu>
    </popup>
</overlay>
```

The newly added Context menu item and submenu items are having transparent background:
[image: Transparent Context Menu Items]

Can anyone help me with the reason behind this and possible fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<popup id="elMenu-popup">` and corresponding `</popup>` to `<menupopup id="elMenu-popup">` and `</menupopup>`